# Is it possible to echo a variable in a recordset result?

Tags: php

I have a PHP page that dynamically determines what City it is referencing. The same page is used for many Cities and needs to have Paragraphs of text that render the $city variable within other texual content.

The content is multiple paragraphs of information stored in a MySQL database and using MySQL RAND() function I pull back different paragraphs to keep things somewhat unique between the many cities. Within these paragraphs are the $city variable.

**The Problem is these paragraphs that contain the $city variable never render the variable value when displayed client side.**

**Details:**
The city is created as a var early in the page (referenced since PHP is a scripting language and works sequentially within the scripted page). Once the city is established I create a variable named: **$city**

For instance the var is created like this:

```
<?php $city = $_GET['city']; ?>
```

This can be used anywhere in the content of the page without issue except in recordset results that are expecting that var to render as if it was rendered in the page (not in a recordset result) proving there is no issue with the variable or how it was created.

To CLARIFY there are instances in the page where $city is used as a simple echo value (static paragraphs). BUT the issue is in RECORDSET values that also contain the variable as shown in the examples below (dynamic paragraphs). Those paragraphs that have the var included in the texual content do not render while the ones set in the page (NOT returned as recordset content) work fine.

I’ve tried setting the database value with (recordset example):

`Something about this <?php echo $city; ?> here. More text here etc etc`

which only renders:
`Something about this here. More text here etc etc`

Then I’ve tried removing the `<?php` wrapper as php IS already processing the recordset value. The result was as shown here:

`Something about $city here. More text here etc etc`

which renders:
`Something about $city here. More text here etc etc` which literally displayed the var as a string.

How would I make a textual record in MySQL return in a state that the variable `$city` renders when displayed on the page?

I'm afraid the answer may require use PHP eval() function on the DB stored results to execute the echo statement. But everything I read on eval() says it is rarely the proper answer. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php
Maybe there is a safer way to get this variable to render in a recordset result?

Comment: write some code or we can not help you

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you wish to accomplish? Because I can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: I've added how the var is set as well as already showed how the values were added when set to the database.

Comment: This question makes no sense to me, either. Using `$city` has nothing to do with the MySQL query.

Comment: The first version, with `<?php echo $city; ?>` should have worked if you set `$city` as you show.

Comment: You need to show the whole code, not just these one-line snippets, so we can see how everything fits together.

Comment: Maybe I gave too much information. I have Paragraphs of textual information saved to a MySQL database. These paragraphs need to display the City differently depending on the where the page is used (It's Dynamic and used for many cities). I need the variable to properly render but it is not working when set in the examples above.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, ```<?php echo $city; ?>``` works perfectly everywhere on the page but fails if this variable is set in the same way in a MySQL recordset value when rendered on the page.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "set in the same way in a MySQL recordset value". Do you mean `mysqli_stmt_bind_value()`?

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: I'll update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to being able to echo a variable within a recordset result is to use the php **eval() function**

`eval('?>'.$row["content"].'<?php;');`

While this works perfectly, the warnings on the PHP Document page are concerning:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php